# WordPress URL Autocorrect

Tags: wordpress, url

I made a typo and tried loading a page that didn't exist (localhost/wordpress-sia/our-missio), but it still took me to the correct page (localhost/wordpress-sia/our-mission).

I'm curious how it autocorrects the URL but couldn't find anything on it. Can someone please explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 3):

The function in WordPress core that does this is [`redirect_canonical()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/redirect_canonical/), which is enabled by default, but can be turned off if you so choose.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/redirect_canonical/

> Search engines consider www.somedomain.com and somedomain.com to be
>   two different URLs when they both go to the same location. This SEO
>   enhancement prevents penalty for duplicate content by redirecting all
>   incoming links to one or the other.
>
> Prevents redirection for feeds, trackbacks, searches, and admin URLs.
>   Does not redirect on non-pretty-permalink-supporting IIS 7+, page/post
>   previews, WP admin, Trackbacks, robots.txt, searches, or on POST
>   requests.
>
> Will also attempt to find the correct link when a user enters a URL
>   that does not exist based on exact WordPress query. Will instead try
>   to parse the URL or query in an attempt to figure the correct page to
>   go to.

Not suggesting that you do, but here's how to disable.

Create this directory and file (a must-use plugin):
`/wp-content/mu-plugins/disable-redirect-canonical.php`

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', function() {
    remove_filter( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
} );
```

*This code could go into your theme's functions.php file if you prefer.*

Answer (score 0):

"**URL Autocorrect Guessing**" can be searched online and it is a default behavior in the WordPress engine. (I didn't find any official explanation but only a few details from other people facing it).  I know also of a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-url-autocorrect-guessing/) that can stop that if you prefer.

I believe it's an included feature that accepts the URL, tries to guess it and then redirects with a 301 Permanent Redirect.

also another question / answer related to this is [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144937/disable-only-url-auto-complete-not-the-whole-canonical-url-system/144970#144970) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92103/disable-wordpress-url-auto-complete)